# I try to apply the CSS on a new template (Post-Header Blogger)

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I try to apply the CSS on a new template especially the Post-Header (Blogger), but it's not working.

I Create a new div and still the same results

CSS :

```css
.post-info{background:transparent;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;color:#fff;font-size:12px;text-align:left;padding:0;box-shadow:none}
.post-info a{display:inline;background:transparent;color:#666;padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;transition:all .3s ease-out}
.post-info a:hover{color:#00BE98}
.author-info,.time-info,.comment-info,.label-info,.review-info{margin-right:8px!important;display:inline-block;color:#666;padding:10px}
.post-info .avatar-author{float:left;border:0;padding:0;width:38px;height:38px;box-shadow:none}
.timestamp-link abbr{border-bottom:none}

#post-header {
    margin: 0 34px 16px 0;
}
```

Post-Header :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0FXN.png]

Template : http://squeeze-landing.blogspot.com

Comment: Post your XML code for helping

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4JsxWL2z

Comment: are you bassam from bramjnet?

Comment: Ok i fix it, i use Blogger Template Designer and add custom CSS.